# Is there a lemmatizer for PHP?

Tags: php

Does anyone know of a [lemmatizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemmatisation) in PHP? Or, at worst, some way to use a lemmatizer in another language (python NLTK, for instance?) in a PHP webapp?

I'm building [a macro-etymological analyzer](http://jonreeve.com/dev/etym/etym.php) and I've encountered this issue where the etymological database doesn't contain conjugated words. A lemmatizer would correct this, I think, by giving me the word "say" when the dictionary can't find "said," and returning "good" when the dictionary can't find "better," etc.

Note: a stemmer wouldn't do the same thing as a lemmatizer.

Comment: Dunno about a lemmatizer, but I could point you toward a Porter Stemmer if that would help (https://github.com/andyceo/PHP-Porter-Stemmer/blob/master/class.stemmer.inc)

Comment: seems like you need to write one.

Comment: This question would perfectly fit [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/). (Providing that you still search for a lemmatizer.)

Comment: I found phpmorphy to work well https://github.com/heromantor/phpmorphy however, I wasn't able to add new lemmatizations to its built in db.  If you figure it out plz let me know

Comment: Pity this question is closed. I'd really like to know the answer too.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt

It's a PHP5 implementation of the Porter Stemmer algorithm.

Comment: Stemmers won't help. I need a lemmatizer.

Answer (score 0):

i googled this:

http://pastebin.com/WNvb2zB4

and this.

http://tartarus.org/~martin/PorterStemmer/php.txt

dunno if any of them works.

Comment: Note that the first one does not have any copyright and/or license information.

Comment: The pastebin piece is actually from a project providing lemmatization for Indonesian language, which is a lot easier to lemmatize than English. https://github.com/davidchristiandy/lemmatizer

Answer (score 0):

Isn't a https://github.com/heromantor/phpmorphy is what you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Lemmatisation is relatively more complicated as compare to stemming, that is why it's harder to find some ready and free solution.

I see nobody answered the sub question.

> some way to use a lemmatizer in another language (python NLTK, for instance?) in a PHP webapp

The php has at least `exec` and calls alike. One can simply run any external script or app.

there are some "lemmatizers" in php that could be found in internet, but at a quick check these are turn to be are "stemmers".

Make sure, Stemming won't do for you. Make sure the solution you already have in mind in other language is a Lemmatizer.

I suspect all solution that close to this naming would be in C-like languages. In case those are Open source or provided as libs you could build them into PHP as an extension.